# NSString is not implicitly convertible to String - but everything is NSString

Tags: string, swift, nsstring

I'm writing code that sets the `Authorization:` header for an `NSMutableURLRequest`:

```
private func setAuthHeader(request: NSMutableURLRequest) {

    let plain       = NSString(format: "%@:%@", self.userName, self.password)
    let plainBytes  = plain.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let headerValue = NSString(format: "Basic %@", plainBytes.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0)))

    request.setValue( headerValue, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization" )
}
```

But when I choose "Go to definition" for `setValue` Xcode shows me it as:

```
- (void)setValue:(nullable NSString *)value forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field;
```

So `setValue` expects an `NSString` parameter value, and `headerValue` is my argument of type `NSString`.

However the Swift compiler gives me this error message:

> RestClient.swift:33:21: '`NSString`' is not implicitly convertible to '`String`'; did you mean to use '`as`' to explicitly convert?

Where is it getting `String` from?

The auto-fix is to change it to this:

```
request.setValue( headerValue as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization" )
```

...but why is that deemed necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the definition you give in your question is the Obj-C signature of the setValue function. The Swift function has the following declaration as you can see in the Apple's documentation of NSMutableURLRequest [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableURLRequest/setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:):

> Declaration
>
> ```
> func setValue(_ value: String?, forHTTPHeaderField field: String)
> ```